# Kibana - dashboard - search visualisation is broken

Tags: kibana-6

Since last version (6.7.1) On every dashboard, search visualise is like

for

Even with dark theme

[image: dark mode activated]

I only have time and source instead of detailed fields

[image: only time and source]

Morever while expanding it, it's white background, quite hard to read
[image: white background on event details]

Does anyone encounter the same issue ?

Comment: Looks like they opened an issue about the dark theme not being applied on some places: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/29417. I found some more on their github page. Your issue seems similar to what is being reported.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved with an update (6.7.2)